# Subdirectories of docker mount not mounted correctly with docker-compose

Tags: mount, docker

#### Problem

Using a data container to store the MySQL data does not work properly if I mount the parent directory /var/lib instead of /var/lib/mysql

#### Infrastructure

I'm using 3 docker containers to provide a website:

- nginx container to run a webserver
- mariadb container for the database
- data container for the created user data

The data container is created using the following docker command:

```
$ docker create \
     -v /var/lib \
     -v /var/www \
     --name [appname]-data \
     tianon/true /bin/true
```

Checking the available mounts for [appname]-data with `$ docker inspect [appname]-data`:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "361ed7b3e38371653f2df75652973e1c48db52d59c4c5371f634c1930291af0c",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/361ed7b3e38371653f2df75652973e1c48db52d59c4c5371f634c1930291af0c/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        ...
```

The containers are started with docker-compose. Both containers should use all mounts available on the data container. My docker-compose.yml:

```
[appname]-nginx:
  container_name: [appname]-nginx
  image: nginx:9-apache
  links:
    - [appname]-mariadb:mysql
  volumes_from:
    - [appname]-data
  restart: always
  expose:
    - "80"

[appname]-mariadb:
  image: mariadb:10.1
  container_name: [appname]-mariadb
  restart: always
  volumes_from:
    - [appname]-data
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pas$w0rd
    TERM: dumb
```

The output of  `$ docker exec -it [appname]-nginx ls -lha /var/lib/mysql`:

```
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 27 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jul 21 10:19 ..
```

The output of `$ docker exec -it [appname]-mariadb ls -lha /var/lib/mysql`:

```
total 109M
drwxr-xr-x 4 mysql mysql 4.0K Jul 21 10:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root  4.0K Jul 21 10:19 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  16K Jul 21 07:57 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   52 Jul 21 07:57 aria_log_control
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  48M Jul 21 07:57 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  48M Jul 21 07:56 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  12M Jul 21 07:57 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    0 Jul 21 07:56 multi-master.info
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Jul 21 07:57 mysql
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Jul 21 07:56 performance_schema
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  24K Jul 21 07:57 tc.log
```

Executing `mount` on both containers shows the same:

```
/dev/dm-0 on /var/lib type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/dm-0 on /var/www type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

However for [appname]-mariadb has an additional mount for /var/lib/mysql exists:

```
/dev/dm-0 on /var/lib/mysql type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

#### Question

Why is it not possible to create a volume mount on /var/lib to save all stored data in the data container?

Do I miss something?

Is it a problem of MySQL / MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your docker volume from `docker-compose.yml` as well?
The following should work:

```
version: '2'                       

services:                          
  nginx:                           
    image: nginx:9-apache          
    expose:                        
      - '80'                       
    volumes:                       
      - app-data:/var/www          
  mariadb:                         
    image: mariadb:10.1            
    volumes:                       
      - app-data:/var/lib          
    environment:                   
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pas$w0rd
      TERM: dumb                   

volumes:                           
  app-data:
```

I wonder why you'd want both containers to store their data on the same volume though. I'd imagine it preferable to store `nginx`'s and `mariadb`'s data in separate volumes.